# Choosing the right Bean at startup

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have got two Beans for DataConnection definied in my App.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.3:3306/gcdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.seconddatasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:gcdboff");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

But because sometimes we do not have any connection to the internet, the first bean is not created at every start, but crashed with a link connection error.

What I have to do, so that my App recognizes - without exception/stop - that the first Configuration is not valid and so have to take the second one.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just throw an exception and let Spring Boot search for another bean.

You could test boths DataSources in the `@Primary` DataSource bean, and return the DataSource that is online.

I've seen that you use `@ConfigurationProperties` so I guess you don't call `dataSource.setPassword` directly in your code. In the example below all the required information would be read from your configuration.

```
   @Primary
   @Bean
   public DataSource getDataSource(
         @Qualifier("first") DataSourceProperties first,
         @Qualifier("second") DataSourceProperties second) {
      final DataSource firstDataSource = first.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
//      try {
//         firstDataSource.getConnection();
//         ...
//      } catch (SQLException e) {
//         ...
//      }

//      return firstDataSource or secondDataSource;
   }

   @Primary
   @Bean("first")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
   public DataSourceProperties  getPrimaryStringProvider() {
      final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = new DataSourceProperties();
      return dataSourceProperties;
   }

   @Bean("second")
   @ConfigurationProperties("spring.seconddatasource")
   public DataSourceProperties getSecondaryStringProvider() {
      return new DataSourceProperties();
   }
```

---

**LE as reply to the comment below:**

> The Exception was wrong. He never entered in the catch block. You have to use a Communication Exception or a Exception it self.

It will throw a SQLException (to be more precise in case of MySQL it probably is `com.mysql.jdbc.public class CommunicationsException extends java.sql.SQLException`).

> Furthermore I have had to enter the beans in the Application class. Otherwise the beans were never build.

You just need to annotate `ApplicationConfiguration` with `@Configuration`.

> I have posted in my question the working solution

I don't think it makes much sense to annotate the method with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")`. The values set in the function will be overwritten with any values *that exist* from the properties file **after** you exit the method `primaryDataSource`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay!!! I had to change a tiny little bit, to work with my solution. The Exception was wrong. He never entered in the catch block. You have to use a Communication Exception or a Exception it self. Furthermore I have had to enter the beans in the Application class. Otherwise the beans were never build. I have posted in my question the working solution. Perhaps you can edit your answer, so I can mark it as correct and rate it... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Tagamoga, I hopefully addressed your concerns in my edit of the answer.

Comment: Hi.. @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource") slipped through, you are right... Unfortunatelly he still does not stops at SQLException... Thank you for help!

Comment: You're welcome. I've tested with SQLException and the catch block catches it. You could post another question on SO with the code if you can't figure out what the exact problem is (don't forget to post the import statements too, to be able to exclude that you're importing the wrong SQLException).